# Rails destroy method in Firefox - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound issue with json rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I've got `destroy` method below for attached files, which works perfectly fine in Chrome but in some how it doesn't work in Firefox - I have to click twice to the **(x)** to delete the file and remove it from the list.

```
  def destroy
    identification_document = IdentificationDocument.find(params[:id])
    authorize identification_document
    identification_document.destroy
    render json: true
  end
```

After first click I've got correct logs form server (I think it's deleted  but the file doesn't disappear from the list)

> Started DELETE "/identification_documents?id=52" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-16 18:46:49 +0200
>   Processing by IdentificationDocumentsController#destroy as JSON
>     Parameters: {"id"=>"52"}
>
> ( ...)
>
> (0.1ms)  BEGIN
>     SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "identification_documents" WHERE "identification_documents"."id" = $1  [["id", 52]]
>
> (0.6ms)  COMMIT
>   Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)

After second click I've got this error in logs and the file finally disappeared from the list

> Started DELETE "/identification_documents?id=52" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-07-16 18:46:58 +0200
>   (...)
>
> Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find IdentificationDocument with 'id'=52):
>
> app/controllers/identification_documents_controller.rb:27:in `destroy'
>
> Rendering /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
>     Rendering /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.7.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb

It looks like firefox by some reason didn't render json. Is this a common error?

**Edit**

Ok, as suggested I update method to:

```
def destroy
  @identification_document = IdentificationDocument.find(params[:id])
  authorize @identification_document

  respond_to do |format|
    if @identification_document.destroy
      format.json { render layout: false }
    else
      format.json { render json: true, status: :bad_request }
    end
  end
end
```

And everything works well (file deleted and disappeared from the list) but I have an error on every single time in the rails server

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
>
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template identification_documents/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:de], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
>
> - "/Users/testapp/app/views"
> - "/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/letter_opener_web-1.3.4/app/views"

How to avoid this error?

Comment: What does the network tab say for the action when performed? It looks like the delete is working as expected for both attempts on the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like on the first click it did perform the delete action on the ID: It is providing a 200 response which identifies that the delete was successful.

On the second click it is then trying to delete an ID that doesn't exist. This is expected, therefore you get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

It could be possible that your javascript isn't correctly picking up the json response. I am guessing this is an AJAX request. Are you checking the status of the response and removing the deleted item from the UI?

Also you should return `head :no_content` on successful `destroy`. Else return `status: :bad_request` on failure. Right now you are just sending true for everything, so your front-end json response doesn't really know if the delete was a success or not.

For delete response, try this:

```
if @identification_document.destroy
  head :no_content
else
  render json: {
    error: 'Could not delete identification document',
    status: :not_found
  }
end
```

Comment: Ok, method updated but even if it works I still have an error from the server - please take a look

Comment: If you change `head` to `:ok` it will work, thanks a lot especially for explanation!